# SQL for one to one between a single table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to know what the best way of reflecting relations between precisely two rows from a single (my)sql table is?

Exemplified, we have:

```
table Person { id, name }
```

If I want to reflect that persons can be married monogamously (in liberal countries at least), is it better to use foreign keys within the Person:

```
table Person { id, name, spouse_id(FK(Person.id)) }
```

and then create stored procedures to marry and divorce Persons (ensuring mutual registration of the marriage or annulment of it + triggers to handle on_delete events..
or use a mapping table:

```
table Marriage { 
 spouse_a(FK(Person.id)), 
 spouse_b(FK,Person.id) + constraint(NOT IN spouse_a))
}
```

This way divorces (delete) would simply be delete queries without triggers to cascade, and marriage wouldn't require stored procedure.
The constraint is to prevent polygamy / multi-marriage

I guess the second option is preferred? What is the best way to do this?
I need to be able to update this relation on and off, so it has to be manageable..

EDIT:
Thanks for the replies - in practice the application is physical point-to-point interfaces in networking, where it really is a 1:1 relationship (monogamous marriage), and change in government, trends etc will not change this :)
I'm going to use a separate table with A & B, having A < B checked..

Comment: Why do you want to prevent polygamy? It's perfectly legal in many countries of the world.

Comment: The only type of constraint that MySQL implements is foreign key. You can't do `CONSTRAINT(NOT IN spouse_a)` automatically, you'd have to use a trigger that checks it.

Comment: The intersection table is the right approach, but I'd make it more general and name it "person_relationships" with a relationship type and date effectivity.  That way, if "spoy" change, you can date it out and the relationships become more open.  The only time you would need more is if each person_id has a specific role in the table, in which case there would be person_one_type, person_two_type (husband / wife for example).  That way, children could be handled as well with (father / son, mother/son).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ensure monogamy, you simply want to ensure that the spouses are unique.  So, this almost does what you want:

```
create table marriage (
    spouse_a int not null unique,
    spouse_b int not null unique
);
```

The only problem is that a given spouse can be in either table.  One normally handles this with a check constraint:

```
check (spouse_a < spouse_b)
```

Voila!  Uniqueness for the relationship.

Unfortunately, MySQL does not support check constraints.  So you can implement this using a trigger or at the application layer.

Comment: Shouldn't the constraint be `constraint uq1 unique (spouse_a, spouse_b)`?

Comment: Alternatively, you could switch to MariaDB 10.2.1 that supports `check` constraints.

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . *Au contraire*.  The point is that each spouse is unique and cannot be in a relationship with anyone else.

Comment: Stupid question, I am still learning about databases: Assume that you have 3 persons with `A < B < C`. As I understand it, the check constraint should correctly prevent that the table contains both `(A,B)` and `(B,A)`, since the second one is invalid. But how can you avoid that the table contains both `(A,B)` and `(B,C)`? This passes the uniqueness constraint of both columns and the check, but this means B is in two relations ...

Answer (score 1):

**Option #1 - Add relationships structurally**

You can add one additional table for every conceivable relationship between two people. But then, when someone asks for a new ralationship you forgot to add structurally, you'll need to add a new table.

And then, there will be relationship for three people at a time. And then four. And then, variable size relationships. You name it.

**Option #2 - Model relationships as tables**

To make it fool proof (well... never possible) you could model the relationships into a new table. This table can have several properties such as `size`, and also you can model restrictions to it. For example, you can decide to have a single person be the "leader of the cult" if you wish to.

This option requires more effor to design, but will resist much more options, and ideas from your client that you never thought before.